# ASP.Net FileUpload not working in google chrome

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, google-chrome

ASP.Net FileUpload not working in google chrome.It shows validation error,even after choosing right file type.Any solution ?

Here is a code :

```
 <asp:FileUpload ID="FU1" runat="server"  />
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator 
    id="FileUpLoadValidator" runat="server" 
    ErrorMessage="Upload jpg and gif only." 
    ValidationExpression="^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w].*))(.jpg|.JPG|.gif|.GIF)$" 
    ControlToValidate="FU1">
    </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you still get the error when you use a more open regex?

```
ValidationExpression="^.+\.((jpg)|(JPG))$"
```